# Create ExpressJS Route Without Registering The Routing Module

Tags: node.js, express

In ExpressJS, you register the routing module like this:

```
app.use(app.router);
```

And you create a route like this:

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res){
  ...
});
```

The problem is, if you create a route before you register the routing module then it is registered for you immediately.

For me, this is a problem because I'm building an NPM module that creates a route for itself. Right now, it has the unfortunate side-effect of registering the routing module without the user's knowledge. So if they happen to require my module before they register the static file handler, then it wrecks everything.

So my question is, how can I register a route without automatically registering the routing module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your module requires the user to pass in their app, kind of like this:

```
module.exports = function(userApp) {
    userApp.get(...);
    ...
}
```

Instead, make a new Express app and export that:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.get(...);
...

module.exports = app;
```

And instead of having the user pass their app to you, have them `use` the app you export:

```
var express = require('express'),
    yourModule = require('your-module'),
    userApp = express();

userApp.use(express.static(...));
userApp.use(yourModule);
```